# need to run command in linux and find result by grep

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep

I am using csf firewall for my server... so i need to run csf -g 10.10.10.10 to check if ip is allowed or not... I am using bash script to run command ... but `csf -g 10.10.10.10` **return 0** if matches found or not found...
so i need to check command result if contain **DENYIN**  for **found** and "**No Matches Found**" for **false**.

i used **grep** but dont know exactly how to use it...
something like this:

```
csf -g 10.10.10.10 && echo === $? ===  || echo $? | grep "No matches found"
```

please let me know about this. if you have better solution please let me know

executed command return:

```
csf -g 10.10.10.10

Table  Chain            num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
No matches found for 10.10.10.10 in iptables


ip6tables:

Table  Chain            num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
No matches found for 10.10.10.10 in ip6tables
```

10.10.10.10 and 20.20.20.20 just for example not not real world case

```
csf -g 20.20.20.20

Table  Chain            num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

filter DENYIN           181   6586  395K DROP       all  --  !lo    * 
20.20.20.20        0.0.0.0/0

filter DENYOUT          181      0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            20.20.20.20


ip6tables:

Table  Chain            num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination No matches found for
20.20.20.20 in ip6tables

csf.deny: 20.20.20.20 # lfd: (smtpauth) Failed SMTP AUTH login from
20.20.20.20 -------: 5 in the last 3600 secs - Thu Oct 24 20:33:07 2019
```

Comment: post possible outputs of `csf -g 10.10.10.10` command

Comment: `$?` contains the return code of the previously executed command. It can only contain a number. 0 means it executed correctly, other numbers usually mean there was a problem. I think you want to check the *standard output* of your program, bu i'm not sure I understood your what you want to do

Comment: `grep` returns 0 if matches found, and 1 otherwise. You could use that return value for your tests.

Comment: code updated... command results add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just filter the standard output and check if there is a result.

Try:

```
    csf -g 10.10.10.10 | grep DENYIN && echo "Found" || echo "No matches found"
```

**A little of explaination:**

There are 4 parts :

1) your command: csf -g ....

2) the grep command will check if the specific string is in the output

3) the && will run the echo command if the grep found the string (exiting 0)

4) the || will run the echo command when the grep didn't found the string

** Tested on: **

```
bash-4.4$ cat testData 
Table  Chain            num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

filter DENYIN           181   6586  395K DROP       all  --  !lo    * 
20.20.20.20        0.0.0.0/0

filter DENYOUT          181      0     0 LOGDROPOUT  all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            20.20.20.20



bash-4.4$ cat testData  | grep -q DENYIN && echo "Found" || echo "No matches found"
Found
```

Comment: this one return bash: !": event not found

Comment: Not on my tests ... anyway just remove the !

Comment: I've tested with your output, it works on my bash... what version are you using?

Comment: now its work great ... thanx ... could you please let me know why ! return bash:!"event not found ?

Comment: if i need to have DENYIN or DENYOUT for Found ... how i can add it ? something like php or many others DENYIN && DENYOUT  /  DENYIN || DENYOUT

Comment: If you want that the result is "Found" if there is DENYIN or DENYOUT you can use grep "DENY\\(OUT\|IN\\)". Note the escaping of the special chars.

Comment: The ! is a special character in bash, depending on how you use it. Inside quotes it shouldn't take it as an event, but I don't know exactly it happened to you. Can you pass the exact command that you used?

Answer (score 1):

If the output is as followed:

```
$ csf -g 192.168.138.1
Chain            num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
No matches found for 192.168.138.1 in iptables
```

You can grep on "No matches found for 192.168.138.1" and use the exit status of grep instead:

```
if csf -g 192.168.138.1 | grep -q "No matches found"; then
    echo "error"
else
    echo "ok"
fi
```

Or even shorter:

```
csf -g 192.168.138.1 | grep -o "No matches found" || echo "Found"
```

Comment: there is 2 No matches found ... for ipv4 and ipv6 ... it never return found because an ip is just ipv4 or ipv6 ... if not found return 2 No matches found ... and if found return 1 No matches found